# Change QT End of Line Style of QTextStream for cross platform Text Editor application

Tags: windows, qt, encoding, cross-platform, line-endings

So I am building a cross platform QT text editor. I am developing on Linux, to target for Windows. I am making it as easy as possible for the user to save the text file with whichever encoding that they wish.

I compiled the project with with `M Cross Environment "MXE"` via the tutorial on their website.

On Linux, everything works perfectly as I want it to so far.

However, on Windows, if I create a file with the text editor (no matter what encoding I choose) and then open it in Notepad, the entire file is in one line.

I am fairly certain that I have found the problem. If I open the file that my QT text editor has created, Emacs says that it has a "Unix" "end of line style."

I am assuming that Windows does not recognize the new line characters because they are Unix style. However, I am unsure how to change the "end of line style" in `QTextStream`. The documentation did not seem to be of any help, and I wasn't able to find anyone else on Stack overflow or otherwise that has the same problem.

The following is my code for saving the file. The `encodeString` variable controls which encoding the file is saved in.

```
void mainwindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    if (!saveFile.isEmpty())
    {
      //"saveFile" is populated with the file name when the file is first opened.
        QFile file(saveFile); 
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            qDebug() << "Could not find file."

        }
        else
        {
      //The following if statements will save the file in the proper encoding dependant on the value of "encodeString."
            QTextStream stream(&file)
            if (encodeString == "Plain Text")
            {
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-8")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-16")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-16");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-16BE")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-16BE");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-32")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-32");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-32BE")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-32BE");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }


        }
    }


}
```

The following is the code for opening the file. It is just streamed to `ui->textEdit` As a secondary question, I would love to be able to record the encoding of the file that is being opened into the value of `encodeString`.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), QString(), tr("All Files (*.*);;Text Files (*.txt);;C++ Files (*.cpp *.h)"));  //Opens the QDialog for opening files.
  saveFile =fileName;       //Sets the value of "saveFile" to the value of "fileName." This insures that any time a "Save" function is performed, the file that the text is saved to, is the one that is intended.
    MainWindow::setWindowTitle(saveFile);
    if(!fileName.isEmpty()) // As long as the file name variable is not empty, this will trigger.
    {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) // If the file could not be opened, it will trigger this error message.
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not open file"));
                        return;
        }
        QTextStream in(&file);      //This sets the variable "in" to be the contents of the file.
    ui->textEdit->setText(in.readAll());    //This sets the text that is in the text edit field to be the contents of the file.
    file.close();       //This closes the file so that no memory errors are caused by having too many files open.
    }
}
```

Comment: How if open the file in text mode, i.e.  `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)`?

Comment: Good point, I will edit the question to include the file opening process.

Comment: I was actually able to find one person that had my question as well here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777334/choose-custom-line-ending-for-text-file-writing-by-qt I am going to work on a solution based off of this answer. In the mean time though, I think that there is an obvious temporary fix. That is to install QT on my Windows machine and build the project with Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly hate answering my own questions on here, but I was actually able to find someone else on the QT forum that had the same problem. That is here https://forum.qt.io/topic/42464/qplaintextedit-eats-line-endings . Using the information from this post and a little tweak, I was able not only to save the files with the proper Windows "line-ending", but I was also able to save the files with the proper encoding. The text in `QTextEdit` is saved to a `Qstring`. The `.replace`function of `Qstring` is then used to change the line ending from `\n` to `\r\n`. The `QTextStream` encoding is then set (or not if it is plain text), and the `Qstring` is streamed to the `QTextStream`. The `QTextStream` is then sent to the file. Saving and manipulation of the `Qstring` is done before the encoding `if` statements to cut down on the amount of code that is needed.

Here is the full save function.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()  // Saves the file
{
    if (!saveFile.isEmpty())
    {
        QString wSave;
        QFile file(saveFile);
        wSave = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
        wSave.replace("\n", "\r\n");
        wSave.replace("\r\r\n", "\r\n");
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))   // This if statement makes sure that the file can be written to.
        {
            // error message

        }
        else
        {
      QTextStream stream(&file);        // Prepares the file to receive the QTextStream
      if (encodeString == "Plain Text")     //The next set of "if" statements set the encoding that the file will be saved in. This is set by the combo box in the text editor.
            {

                qDebug() << wSave;
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-8")
            {

                stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-16")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-16");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-16BE")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-16BE");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-32")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-32");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }

            if (encodeString == "UTF-32BE")
            {
                stream.setCodec("UTF-32BE");
                stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);
                stream << wSave;
                stream.flush();
                file.close();
            }


        }
    }


}
```